# How to specify that a lifetime from an impl should be the same as the lifetime of 'self'?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm starting from a root `Fmt` and descending recursively (along a `Vec<String>`) into `Fmt`s produced by a `get_subfmt` call. When the vector is empty, I call a method (not shown here for brevity). Each preceding `Fmt` (and its `BoxOrRef`) has naturally greater lifetime enforced by the recursive function's scope than the following one. This seems safe, but I'm very new to the lifetimes business, so I may have erred in my reasoning somewhere.

Consider the following bit of simplified code:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

pub trait Fmt {
    fn get_subfmt<'a>(&'a self, name: &str) -> Option<BoxOrRef<'a, dyn Fmt>>;
}

pub enum BoxOrRef<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> {
    Boxed(Box<T>),
    Ref(&'a T)
}

impl<'b, T: Borrow<dyn Fmt + 'b>> Fmt for T {
    fn get_subfmt(&'b self, name: &str) -> Option<BoxOrRef<'b, dyn Fmt>> {
        self.borrow().get_subfmt(name)
    }
}
```

This fails with the following errors:

```
error[E0308]: method not compatible with trait
  --> src/lib.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     fn get_subfmt(&'b self, name: &str) -> Option<BoxOrRef<'b, dyn Fmt>> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(&'a T, &str) -> std::option::Option<BoxOrRef<'a, Fmt + 'a>>`
              found type `fn(&'b T, &str) -> std::option::Option<BoxOrRef<'b, Fmt + 'b>>`
note: the lifetime 'a as defined on the method body at 13:5...
  --> src/lib.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     fn get_subfmt(&'b self, name: &str) -> Option<BoxOrRef<'b, dyn Fmt>> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime 'b as defined on the impl at 12:1
  --> src/lib.rs:12:1
   |
12 | impl<'b, T: Borrow<dyn Fmt + 'b>> Fmt for T {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0308]: method not compatible with trait
  --> src/lib.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     fn get_subfmt(&'b self, name: &str) -> Option<BoxOrRef<'b, dyn Fmt>> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(&'a T, &str) -> std::option::Option<BoxOrRef<'a, Fmt + 'a>>`
              found type `fn(&'b T, &str) -> std::option::Option<BoxOrRef<'b, Fmt + 'b>>`
note: the lifetime 'b as defined on the impl at 12:1...
  --> src/lib.rs:12:1
   |
12 | impl<'b, T: Borrow<dyn Fmt + 'b>> Fmt for T {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the method body at 13:5
  --> src/lib.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     fn get_subfmt(&'b self, name: &str) -> Option<BoxOrRef<'b, dyn Fmt>> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It seems that the compiler can't prove that the `'a` from the definition of `get_subfmt` is the same as `'b` from the `impl`, most likely because I haven't told it that it is. How do I communicate to the compiler that I want the `self` reference to last precisely `'b`? I can't slap a `<'a: 'b>` on the `get_subfmt` in the `impl`, as that doesn't match the method signature. I've tried constraining `T` to be `T: Borrow<dyn Fmt + 'b> + 'b`, but that doesn't help, the errors remain.

I could move `'a` from the method to the `Fmt` itself, but it doesn't really seem right, so I would like to avoid it if there's a way to.

Comment: Why do you want to do any of what you ask? Why do you believe what you are asking is memory-safe? Why is *I want the `self` reference to last precisely `'b`* a valid thing to do?

Comment: @Shepmaster The use case is that I start from a root `Fmt` and descend recursively (along a `Vec<String>`) into `Fmt`s produced by a `get_subfmt` call, and when the vector is empty, call a method not shown here for brevity. So each preceding `Fmt` (and its `BoxOrRef`) has naturally greater lifetime enforced by the recursive function's scope than the following one. This seems safe, but I'm very new to the lifetimes business, so I may have erred in my reasoning somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

pub trait Fmt<'b> {
    fn get_subfmt<'a>(&'a self, name: &str) -> Option<BoxOrRef<'a, dyn Fmt + 'a>>
    where
        'b: 'a;
}

pub enum BoxOrRef<'a, T: ?Sized + 'a> {
    Boxed(Box<T>),
    Ref(&'a T)
}

impl<'b, T: Borrow<dyn Fmt<'b> + 'b>> Fmt<'b> for T {
    fn get_subfmt<'a>(&'a self, name: &str) -> Option<BoxOrRef<'a, dyn Fmt + 'a>>
    where
        'b: 'a,
    {
        self.borrow().get_subfmt(name)
    }
}
```

We want the bound `'b: 'a` (`'b` outlives `'a`), not `'a: 'b`, because a borrowed reference cannot outlive its referent.

Comment: So moving the lifetime to the trait is the way to go. Oh well. Thank you.